# JQuery .css() ignoring previous changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, typography

I have a color picker and a typography selector that change the color and font of a text. In order to do so, I have the following JQuery code:

```
// Title color
$(".pick-a-color").on("change", function() 
{
    $(".preview-header-text").css("color", "#" + $(this).val());
});

// Title typography
$(".form-control").change(function()
{
    $(".preview-header-text").css("font-family", $(this).val());
});
```

The problem is that if I first change the typography and then the color, the typography also changes and resets to the default typography. It doesn't happen the other way round, if I change the color and then the typography, the color doesn't reset to the default color.

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle?

Comment: can you provide your html code, or better a fiddle?

Comment: who are the people voting up for this? can they please say why they did so? kinda confused here! :)

Comment: It's working fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/H75F8/1/

Comment: It was actually that by mistake I had put to both selectors the `.form-control` class. Thanks anyway! @jacelysh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks OK.

The `.form-control` selects the `form` element or the font-family `input`?

Add a `console.log($(this).val());` in the `change` function.

Comment: `.form-control` is the class of only the typography input.

Comment: No, actually I reviewed the code and it's not, one fo the classes of the object with `.pick-a-color` class is also `.form-control`. That's clearly the error. Thanks!